# How to extract the 7th character from a ID

Tags: delphi

I have to extract the 7th character of someone's ID that they enter through an InputBox.

So far I only have the InputBox, I need to extract the 7th character but have no idea on how to do it.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ID : string;
begin
  ID := Inputbox ('ID', 'Enter ID', '');
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried `ID[7]`?

Comment: Just make sure that there *is* a seventh character before you access `ID[7]`. That's very important. `if Length(ID) < 7 then raise Exception.Create('Too few characters') else ShowMessage(IntToStr(ID[7]))`. Alternatively, do `Copy(ID, 7, 1)` instead of `ID[7]`. That simply gives you the empty string if there aren't seven chars.

Comment: `Copy(ID, 7, 1)` is the safest way to do it. It will return the 7th character if the ID is at least 7 characters long, and will return the empty string `(''`)` if it's shorter than 7 characters.